# Delete file from server based on database query asp.net vb

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have a file folder that contains pdf files. The sql database is not directly related to the files. For example, I have "Invoice_co_355_24636.pdf" and "Invoice_co_355_25127.pdf" in the Invoices folder. I query the database and find that Invoice "24636" is not paid and "25127" is marked paid in full, so I would like to delete "Invoice_co_355_25127.pdf" at that point since it is paid.

So what I'm doing is getting all the file names from the folder, parsing each file to get just the last numbers, (which correlate to the database). If the database shows that one or more of the Invoices has been paid, I would like to delete the file.

I have successfully, (below), been able to parse the server file names as

"InvNo" as the parsed file name, (which corelates to the database), and

"InvNoFull", which is the full database file name that needs to be deleted if it is marked as paid in the database.

But after getting the file names and the parsed file names, I do not know how to actually compare it to the database and then delete. Any help is appreciated.

```
     Dim files() As String = Directory.GetFiles(Server.MapPath("/Contents/Invoices/" + Variable.ToString() + "/Co/" + ddlCo.SelectedValue.ToString() + "/"))
        For Each file As String In files
            Dim InvNo As String = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(file)
            Dim InvNoFull As String = Path.GetFileName(file)
            InvNo = InvNo.Substring(InvNo.LastIndexOf("_") + 1, InvNo.Length - InvNo.LastIndexOf("_") - 1)

            Dim CnStr As String = (ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("ClientConnectionString").ConnectionString)
            Dim adp As SqlDataAdapter = New SqlDataAdapter("select OrderBilling.OrderId from orderBilling Left Outer Join Orders on OrderBilling.OrderId = Orders.OrderId Where Orders.CompanyId = " & ddlCo.SelectedValue.ToString() & " And Orders.OwnerId = " & Variable.ToString() & " And OrderBilling.PaidInFull = 'False'", CnStr)
            Dim ds As DataSet = New DataSet()
            adp.Fill(ds, "outBill")

            For Each Row As DataRow In ds.Tables(0).Rows
                For Each Coll As DataColumn In ds.Tables(0).Columns
                    Dim s As String = Row(Coll.ColumnName).ToString()
                    If s <> InvNo Then
                        Dim FileToDelete() As String
                        FileToDelete = Directory.GetFiles(Server.MapPath("/Contents/Invoices/" + Variable.ToString() + "/Co/" + ddlCo.SelectedValue.ToString() + "/" + InvNoFull))
                        If System.IO.File.Exists(FileToDelete.ToString()) = True Then
                            System.IO.File.Delete(FileToDelete.ToString())
                            'MsgBox("File Deleted")

                        End If
                    End If
                Next
            Next
        Next
```

With help from Mary but this deletes all the files in the folder, but I want it to delete only the files not returned in the database query:

```
Private Sub DeletePaidInvoices(OwnerID2 As String, CompanyID As String)
    Dim InvoicePath = "/Contents/Invoices/" & OwnerID2 & "/Co/" & CompanyID & "/"
    Dim files() As String = Directory.GetFiles(Server.MapPath(InvoicePath))
    Dim lst = GetInvoiceInfo(CInt(CompanyID), CInt(OwnerID2))
    For Each file As String In files
        Dim InvNo As String = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(file)
        Dim InvNoFull As String = Path.GetFileName(file)
        InvNo = InvNo.Substring(InvNo.LastIndexOf("_") + 1, InvNo.Length - InvNo.LastIndexOf("_") - 1)
        'Debug.Print(InvNo) 'To check your substring, will not be in release version
        For Each i As Integer In lst
            Dim s As String = i.ToString()
           
            If s <> InvNo Then
                Dim FileToDelete As String
                FileToDelete = "Invoice_co_" & CompanyID & "_" & InvNo & ".pdf"
                If System.IO.File.Exists(Server.MapPath(InvoicePath & FileToDelete.ToString())) = True Then
                    System.IO.File.Delete(Server.MapPath(InvoicePath & FileToDelete.ToString()))

                End If

            End If
        Next
    Next

End Sub
```

Comment: If that file is the only hard copy you have of the actual Invoice, I would not delete it but move it to a Paid folder.

Comment: Good idea. I'm open to that idea, still don't know how to isolate that file and move it. I have all the data on the database to create a new invoice if needed, however.

Comment: Your Select statement looks a bit strange. After the Join clause, which I presume is PK to a FK, It seems the rest belongs in a Where clause.

Comment: Yes you are correct I fixed it on my post. thanks!

Comment: Is the datatype of OwnerID and CompanyID in the orders table really a String? Many times ID's are Int so they can be auto- incremented in their source table.

Comment: Well, taking the opposite approach to Mary.  If you've got all the info to recreate the pdf, why keep a copy of it anyway?  Also don't confuse "+" and "&" when concatenating strings, might be getting some unexpected results.  What exactly about your code above doesn't work?  I don't understand the "compare it to the db and delete part.  To me looks like you are

Comment: If the pdf is actually in the file folder then It can be emailed as an attachment. I currently can't create pdf from database and email it. Maybe someday I'll learn that. But I need to query database and if the value in the database says paid in full, I want to delte that pdf. Right now I can't get the code to find and delete. Basically I found the file, and then I queried the database and nothing works after that.

Comment: OwnerId and CompanyId are Int type in database, but the query works for me, even if it is wrong

Comment: All the comments to your question are addressed to you but it is easier to tell who you are talking to when you respond if you precede your comment with @ACommentsName.

Comment: How about the datatype of PaidInFull. I would expect bit.

Comment: You have only retrieved a single column in your Select statement so why the For loop for the Columns?

Comment: Another type question... What is the datatype in the database of OrderBilling.OrderId. Again as an id I would expect Int.

Comment: yes it only returns one value "paidinfull" which is bit. I just need to know if the invoice number is NOT included in the dataset returned from the database. OrderBilling.OrderId is int. Again, the sql query returns the data correctly. It returns all unpaid invoices. So I need to delete or move an invoice if it is not in the list of returned values

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Call your delete method from, say, a button passing the variable from the user interface.

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim CompID = ddlCo.SelectedValue.ToString()
    Dim OwnerID = "comes from somewhere"
    DeletePaidInvoices(OwnerID, CompID)
End Sub
```

The delete method gets the file list. I have no idea about Server.MapPath but I assume you do. Next we get a List(Of Integer) representing the results of you database query (the `OrderID`'s). Next we enter the `For` loop. I added a `Debug` line to see what is being returned by `SubString` code. As you can see it is simpler code to loop through a list.

```
Private Sub DeletePaidInvoices(OwnerID As String, CompanyID As String)
    Dim InvoicePath = $"/Contents/Invoices/{OwnerID}/Co/{CompanyID}/"
    Dim files() As String = Directory.GetFiles(Server.MapPath(InvoicePath))
    Dim lst = GetInvoiceInfo(CInt(CompanyID), CInt(OwnerID))
    For Each file As String In files
        Dim InvNo As String = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(file)
        Dim InvNoFull As String = Path.GetFileName(file)
        InvNo = InvNo.Substring(InvNo.LastIndexOf("_") + 1, InvNo.Length - InvNo.LastIndexOf("_") - 1)
        Debug.Print(InvNo) 'To check your substring, will not be in release version
        For Each i As Integer In lst
            Dim s As String = i.ToString()
            If s <> InvNo Then
                Dim FileToDelete() As String
                FileToDelete = Directory.GetFiles(Server.MapPath(InvoicePath & InvNoFull))
                If System.IO.File.Exists(FileToDelete.ToString()) = True Then
                    System.IO.File.Delete(FileToDelete.ToString())
                    'MsgBox("File Deleted")
                End If
            End If
        Next
    Next
End Sub
```

The data retrieval is in a separate function. Use `Using` blocks to make sure your connections and commands are closed and disposed. Always use parameters with Sql Server. There is a bit of Linq magic at the end to create the list from the `DataTable`.

```
Private Function GetInvoiceInfo(CompanyID As Integer, OwnerID As Integer) As List(Of Integer)
    Dim dt As New DataTable
    Using cn As New SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("ClientConnectionString").ConnectionString),
            cmd As New SqlCommand("select OrderBilling.OrderId 
                                        from orderBilling 
                                        Left Outer Join Orders on OrderBilling.OrderId = Orders.OrderId 
                                        Where Orders.CompanyId = @CompanyID 
                                        And Orders.OwnerId = @OwnerID 
                                        And OrderBilling.PaidInFull = @Paid;", cn)
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@CompanyID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = CompanyID
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@OwnerID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = OwnerID
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@Paid", SqlDbType.Bit).Value = False
        cn.Open()
        dt.Load(cmd.ExecuteReader)
    End Using
    Dim lstOrderID As List(Of Integer) = (From dRow In dt.AsEnumerable() Select dRow.Field(Of Integer)(0)).ToList
    Return lstOrderID
End Function
```

The actual deleting of the files (or moving to a Paid folder) is up to you.

Comment: I'm working on implementing this. I'm not sure what the VB equivalent is for "$". Character is not valid in vb

Comment: Yes, it is valid from Visual Studio 2015 forward. You can use String.Format if you are using a Visual Studio older than 2015 of go back to concatenating strings.

Comment: With a few tweaks I got it to delete all the files in that folder. It does not find the one that is not there, but it deletes all the files. I'll update my code to see what I have

Comment: Now when I changed in this line it deltes all the invocies, except the paid ones. opposite of what I want: FileToDelete = "Invoice_co_" & CompanyID & "_" & s & ".pdf"

Comment: It seems your Select statement is only returning .PaidInFull = False. I just follow your original Select statement. Maybe that should be True.

Comment: Oh dang it worked (changing PaidInFull = True). I also had to change in FileToDelte to "s" instead of "InvNo" but wow thank you. It does feel like magic!